# Why I couldn't work with a dictionary in different keywords in the Robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I want to work with the dictionary in different keywords. But I get the error when I try to work with the dictionary in another keyword:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

This is my sample code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Collections

*** Variables ***
&{PRODUCTS}

*** Keywords ***
Set the Dictionary
  &{PRODUCTS} =  create dictionary  OrderN=R0
      ...  OrderPersonal=No_Account OrderPosition=EmptyPosition

Get the Dictionary
  log dictionary  \&{PRODUCTS}

*** Test Cases ***
Using the dictionary type of variables
  Set the Dictionary
  Get the Dictionary
  set to dictionary  &{PRODUCTS}  OrderPosition  TestPosition
  Get the Dictionary
```

Why is the variable not accessible in another keyword? How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because of Robot Framework variable scope. This is explained in the following Robot Framework guide section: [Variable priorities and scopes](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-priorities-and-scopes).

In this case I think you should use one of the [Set Test/Suite/Global Variable keywords](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-set-test-suite-global-variable-keywords) to store the variable outside the keyword scope.

```
*** Keywords ***
Set the Dictionary
  &{PRODUCTS} =  create dictionary  OrderN=R0
      ...  OrderPersonal=No_Account OrderPosition=EmptyPosition
  Set Test Variable    ${PRODUCTS}    &{PRODUCTS}
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay! Please update the last string to the `Set Test Variable  ${PRODUCTS}  &{PRODUCTS}` and I'll mark the response as accepted.